# Compatibility of http-builder-ng Groovy module with Jenkins 2

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, groovy, java, jenkins2

Did somebody had a chance to use http-builder-ng Groovy module in Jenkins pipeline?

When I use this module with any kind of request/URL it always returns me null object when the same source code from my Desktop is being run fine.

Here is debug output:

```
<groovyx.net.http.UriBuilder$Basic@4bc2413c scheme=http port=-1 host=api.open-notify.org path=/astros.json query=[:] fragment=null userInfo=null parent=groovyx.net.http.UriBuilder$ThreadSafe@69c6847a useRawValues=null>
```

The older version of this module developed by groovy.codehouse works fine, but it doesn't have some methods which I need.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against importing if at all possible. You can use built-in functionality to achieve the same results. Also be aware of "[In-process Script Approval](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/)"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662243/1678094

```java
// GET
def get = new URL("https://httpbin.org/get").openConnection();
def getRC = get.getResponseCode();
println(getRC);
if(getRC.equals(200)) {
    println(get.getInputStream().getText());
}


// POST
def post = new URL("https://httpbin.org/post").openConnection();
def message = '{"message":"this is a message"}'
post.setRequestMethod("POST")
post.setDoOutput(true)
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
post.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
println(postRC);
if(postRC.equals(200)) {
    println(post.getInputStream().getText());
}
```

You can also override the request method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32503192/1678094

```java
conn.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: Default built in module doesn't have a PATCH method. I was trying  to apply other workarounds, but they do not work with Jenkins groovy. I created related question on developer forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521559/java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-invoke-method-get-on-null-object

Comment: Updated with an additional workaround.

Comment: As I mentioned I tried workarounds and this one as well. It didn't work out for my case.